# Memory leak in chrome.extension.sendRequest()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome Version       : 9.0.597.19 (Build 68937) beta & current stable

I have simplified my code as far as possible. I ended up with the attached extension:

```
content.js (content script run on every site):
setInterval(function() {
 chrome.extension.sendRequest({ }, function(response) {
  //Do nothing
 });
}, 1);

background.js (background page script):
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 sendResponse({ });
});
```

When you install this extension, you can observe it eating up memory extremely fast (I got 90MB in 1 min with 9 tabs opened). You can speed up the process by opening more tabs.

Of course, the extension I am actually developing does not send requests every millisecond, but only every 3 seconds. This just slows it down, though. A user who has run it in the background for a long time with many tabs opened has reported 100MB of memory usage, and I can reproduce it to a less extreme extent, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a question so maybe answering is not relevant but,

In order to progress from this point you should do 3 things:
    1. Test it on the latest chromium version. (Can be downloaded - [here](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/))
    2. Check the issues list [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).
    3. If it has not been reported, report an issue at the left hand corner (new issue) on the link in step 2.

Good luck,
Be happy, Julian

Comment: Thanks, from my experience it takes a few days until someone addresses it.